# Youtube API v3 search.list returning irrelevant videos Swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I'm trying to do something very simple; get the same video results displayed in my app as are displayed when you search Youtube.com and sort by `Upload count`.

Almost everything else works fine, I can:

- fetch the thumbnail, title, and channel name
- play the video

*Working on getting each video's view count too (I've heard you need
   to create two requests?)

What really confuses me is how this code:

```
var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?
part=snippet
&fields=items(id,snippet(title,channelTitle,thumbnails))
&order=viewCount
&q=\(searchBar.text)
&type=video
&maxResults=25&key=\(apiKey)"
```

produces this result:

[image]

instead of something like this:

*Excluding the playlist

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

```
  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Form the request URL string.
        var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=items(id,snippet(title,channelTitle,thumbnails))&order=viewCount&q=\(searchBar.text)&type=video&maxResults=25&key=\(apiKey)"

        urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

        // Create a NSURL object based on the above string.
        let targetURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

        // Get the results.
        performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in
            if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary object.
                let resultsDict = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                // Get all search result items ("items" array).
                let items: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                // Loop through all search results and keep just the necessary data.
                for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i {
                    let snippetDict = items[i]["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                    //                    let statisticsDict = items[i]["statistics"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                    // Create a new dictionary to store the video details.
                    var videoDetailsDict = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
                    videoDetailsDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                    videoDetailsDict["channelTitle"] = snippetDict["channelTitle"]
                    videoDetailsDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]
                    videoDetailsDict["videoID"] = (items[i]["id"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["videoId"]
                    //                    videoDetailsDict["viewCount"] = statisticsDict["viewCount"]

                    self.videosArray.append(videoDetailsDict)

                    // Reload the tableview.
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }
            else {
                print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
                print("Error while loading channel videos: \(error)")
            }

        })

    }


    // MARK: Custom method implementation

    func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURL!, completion: (data: NSData?, HTTPStatusCode: Int, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)
            })
        })

        task.resume()
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was quite simple actually, much to my relief/frustration.

In the url, this was the issue:

```
\(searchBar.text)
```

`searchBar.text` is an optional and that's why the results were coming back different from the youtube.com search.  Simple fix:

```
\(searchBar.text!)
```